# copy files from one solaris 9 to another using java

Tags: java, ssh

How to copy file(s) from one solaris 9 machine to another solaris 9 machine using only java?

We have ssh access to both machines. The java program will run on one of those two machines.

Update: rsync is not really an option. can't install it easily (UNIX team is, hum, hard to deal with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the ssh library jsch -- http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/. This program is used by ant to do ssh transfers. very good -- been there a long time(> 5 years), decent documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Runtime.exec() to launch [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/).

Comment: You could lanunch scp as well, I guess. If you really only have the ability to install your program on one of the pair of computers, using exec() is probably the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use FTP. Or you could mount some shared storage.

Comment: We're going that route. Recommendations on FTP classes for java (1.5) for this setup?

Answer (score 1):

if you're headed the way of FTP, here's 2 libraries

1) http://www.geocities.com/SiliconValley/Code/9129/javabean/ftpbean/
2) http://commons.apache.org/net/